# Segmented FileStream Write

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-2.0

I use a segmented http download using ranges (HttpWebRequest.AddRanges())  splitting a file in parts and then joining all parts. If a file is 100 bytes I split it in 4 parts (0-24, 25-49, 50-74, 75-99) and I call four times DownloadPart function. 
Each part is downloaded using asynchronous programming model (BeginRead/EndRead). When all parts are completed I join them, part1+ part2+ ...

```
 public void DowloadPart(HttpWebResponse httpResp)
    {
        Stream httpStm = httpResp.GetResponseStream(); 
        Stream fileStm = new FileStream("myFile.part1", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 16];

        AsyncCallback callback = null;
        callback = ar =>
        {
            int bytesRead = httpStm.EndRead(ar);
            fileStm.Write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
            if(bytesRead == 0)
                return;

            httpStm.BeginRead(buff, 0, buff.Length, callback, null);
        };
        httpStm.BeginRead(buff, 0, buff.Length, callback, null);
    }
```

I want to replace parts joining with directly writing to the file. Since all "DownloadPart" are running in different threads what is the best way to write concurrently to the FileStream in different positions from different threads?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I filled "myFile" (without using parts) and I got System.IO.IOExeption (Another thread may have caused an unexpected change in the position of the operating system's file handle)

Comment: It's not clear why that would have happened on a single thread.

Comment: I did not use a single thread in direct writing (as I stated in my question)

Comment: Then surely, the exception is quite clear: let each thread use a separate `FileStream`

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you would grow the file first to the desired size, which is not trivial. The API to use exists only as native API, namely [`SetFileValidData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and requires special `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE` for the process. The (huge) advantage is that the file grows to the desired size *without being first filled with 0s*. For those familiar with databases this is known as [Instant File Initialization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

If you don't want to go to this trouble then you can grow the file the traditional way, but you'll pay the price of writing the content *twice*, once as 0s once as valid content.

Once you have the file at the right size the best API to write the content is [`WriteFileGather`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Scatter/Gather IO allows you to write arbitrary file segments at arbitrary offsets. But, again, is native only and has no managed counterpart...

W/o scatter/gather IO another decent option is memory mapped access. Luckily this has a managed API,[`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)... for .Net 4.0.

W/o  memory mapped IO you must use one single stream for all the writing. This means you must use a producer-consumer pattern in which the web streams produce buffers to write (annotated with file offset to write at!) and one consumer takes these buffers and writes them at the appropriate position in the out stream.

Comment: If I set the length of the file in the first FileStream (SetLength()),  then start writing from different positions (FileStream.Position) in each stream/thread is guaranteed that I will not have threading issues and the file will be correct?

Comment: At the very least you have to protect the Position (only one thread at time can set the position and issue a write). I would consider *much* safer to have a dedicated writer that does just that (position/write).

Comment: No, I thought having four FileStreams each starting from Position=0,  25, 50, 75 (for a file of 100 bytes).

Comment: You can't have four file streams. AFAIK a process cannot open the same file multiple times for writes through the normal file IO API. This where memory mapped IO would help, because you *can* open multiple views, at different offsets, into the same file.